# Changing the point of Rotation of an Object

Tags: rotation

I have an object that I can rotate and resize etc using GDI+ and transforms.  The rotation point can be dragged so that it is at any point. Resize & rotation works fine, except for one feature.

What I'm struggling to work out how to do with transformations is how to take an object that is already rotated about a rotation point, then move that rotation point and for the object to stay at it's current position (just the rotation point has moved). Visio does this nicely!

I presume the top left origin is changing on the object (when not rotated) or the angle is changing?

Can anyone advise possibly with an example if possible as this is driving me nuts;  I'm sure it's simple but cant find a solution in this forum.  Anyone done before out there?

```
' Setup Variables
Dim OrigLocation as Point = .....
Dim OrigRotationAt as PointF = .....
Dim NewRotationAt as PointF = .....
Dim Rotation as Single = .....

' Matrix Transformation
Dim TransPoints As Point() = New Point() {OrigLocation}
Dim mat As New Matrix
mat.Translate(OrigLocation.X, OrigLocation.Y, MatrixOrder.Append)
mat.RotateAt(Rotation, OrigRotationAt, MatrixOrder.Append)
mat.RotateAt(-Rotation, NewRotationAt, MatrixOrder.Append)
mat.Translate(-OrigLocation.X, OrigLocation.Y, MatrixOrder.Append)
mat.TransformPoints(TransPoints)
mat.Dispose()

' Set New Location
Dim NewLocation as Point = TransPoints(0)
```

Regards

Julian Wigman

Comment: You need to provide a minimal example.

Comment: See original post; now added.

Comment: Any ideas....anybody out there!!!  :0)